# Android: Modify dataset on a custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a CustomAdapter where i set a `OnLongClickListener()`. On that listener I can delete some data from my ListView.

The Activity where I display that ListView I use some logic to display a TextView when there is no data to display...

When the activity resume i check if list size is > 0...

When I start my App and ther isn't no data the TextView is displayed.

When I create new data, the ListView display it...

When I delete some data, on my customadapter, I call `notifyDataSetChanged();` and it's working when the list size change to any value diferent of 0... If there is 2 itens, it's refresh to 1. But if there is 1, and I delete it, a empty ListView is displayed, but not my TextView...

How can I call `MyActivity.onResume()` from my `CustomAdapter`?

Comment: Use the `ListView#setEmptyView()` method, instead of trying to hide/show that `TextView` yourself. The `ListView` will handle setting its visibility appropriately.

Comment: It's working now. Put that on Answer to me aprove it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. It's a pretty frequent question here, however, so I'll mark this as a duplicate, instead. I just wanted to first make sure I correctly understood what you're trying to do. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!